# How can I change playback speed of mpv video player?

Tags: video-player, mpv-media-player

I love mpv player for its modern minimalist look, easy moving along a video simply with mouse scroll and robust rendering of `.mp4` videos.

However, I could not figure out how to change the playback speed as I can do easily in VLC's playback menu. I simply can not see any GUI option to do so. Nor could I find a relevant configuration trick in the [wiki](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/wiki/FAQ).

So I appreciate your hints if there is a hidden button or a configuration tweak to define a shortcut key to do so.  I'm using mpv on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See the [manual](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#keyboard-control) (or [`man mpv`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/mpv.1.html#interactive%20control)):

> #### Keyboard Control
>
> ...
>
> <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd>
>        Decrease/increase current playback speed by 10%.
>
> <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd>
>        Halve/double current playback speed.
>
> <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>
>        Reset playback speed to normal.

Answer (score 3):

[`man mpv(1)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/mpv.1.html) documents also `--speed` command line option (for short videos there is unpractical to use `[` or `{` keyboard shortcuts):

```
$ mpv --speed=0.2 media.ogg
```